# ¿Cómo "feria" ganó el significado de "dinero"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, diferencias-regionales, historia, hispanoamérica

En algunos países latinoamericanos se denomina "feria" al dinero.

Muy a menudo se utiliza para referirse al cambio o a dinero sin contabilizar en monedas.

Ejemplos:

> Me dieron 20 pesos de feria. (*cambio*)
>
> Se te cayeron las feriecitas. (*tiró las monedas*)
>
> Saca la feria. (*en un robo*)

Comment: Otro ejemplo: --¿Quieres ir al cine?  --No, mano, no tengo feria [=plata, dinero].

Comment: "La de saber por qué le decimos a las cosas con un sobrenombre, como es el caso de decir lana, feria o baro al dinero. Lo de la feria va más enfocado a la morralla, pues cuando uno va (mejor dicho cuando íbamos, ya que ahora todo está caro), se requería llevar moneda fraccionaria para comprar sin dificultad lo mucho que allí se vende;" http://vamonosalbable.blogspot.com/2014/12/por-que-le-decimos-lana-al-dinero.html

Comment: por cierto, ten en cuenta que aplica para México, Guatemala, Honduras, Nicaragua y El Salvador (o eso dice la [ASALE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=feria) )

Comment: Simplemente es un uso coloquial del lenguaje. Se debe procurar realizar un comentario con un español claro y que sea universal para todos los hispanohablantes

Comment: Puede ser que viene de *feria* -> *[feriar](https://dle.rae.es/feriar)* -> *feria*

Comment: En qué ciudad se le dice feria al dinero

Comment: RAE: 11. f. coloq. El Salv. y Méx. dinero (‖ moneda corriente).

Answer (score 1):

**Cuestión:** ¿Cómo "feria" ganó el significado de "dinero"?

La expresión "feria como dinero" procede de los niños, normalmente piden dinero para ir ó cuando están con sus Papás en la Feria y protestan y suplican pidiendo dinero para montarse en las diferentes atracciones. Así habitualmente el dinero que se entrega por los papás a los niños es "calderilla,  morralla, suelto", es decir, dinero en monedas ya que para utilizar cualquier máquina ó montarse en una noria, en un "tío-vivo", en el tren de la bruja.... ó jugar a la tómbola, solo necesitas dinero en monedas, por eso es "dinero de feria", dinero en monedas, dinero chatarra para montar en los cacharritos.

La expresión, como suele ocurrir, acabo reduciéndose para ser interpretada en un sentido amplio dinero, dinero para los cacharros, aunque se sobrentienda "dinero en monedas". Ello ha conformado otras muchas locuciones ya sea para decir que no "tienes feria", no tienes dinero, "Dame la feria", ¡dame el dinero, te estoy atracando! ó "ve a por feria", ve a por cambio. Espero te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

**Definición de feria**:

1. Mercado que se celebra al aire libre en unas fechas determinadas y en el que se compran y se venden todo tipo de productos, especialmente agrícolas y ganaderos.
2. Evento en el cual se paga una cantidad (relativamente) pequeña de dinero a cambio de participar en un sorteo con premios. (a raffle)

Note: sporadically some raffles are free and you can get some money.

---

**Hecho implicito**: En las ferias normalmente se encuentran atracciones (games) donde puedes ganar un premio invirtiendo poco dinero.

---

**Contextual meaning**: Inferring by the context you may think, "Feria" has a connotation of wining something without much effort, just for fun (as when you go to the attractions in the carnival) or *to get money for free* which is more likely to be the origin of that contextual meaning for "Feria". It is not *just* that "Feria" is an interchangeable word for money it also can be conceived as the event which lead people to get money.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo que se realiza en las ferias es el intercambio de dinero, un bien por otro. Supongo que por eso ha evolucionado en esa dirección

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Según Jorge Mejías en su [diccionario de mexicanismos](https://books.google.cl/books?id=yrD7X-KZBCcC),

> ...En la lengua castellana, *feriar* significa vender, comprar o permutar alguna cosa. De esta idea de permuta o cambio se tomó en México el sentido de cambio monetario y, extensivamente, de moneda fraccionaria.

El significado provendría, entonces, del dinero fraccionario (el "[cambio](https://dle.rae.es/cambio)"), y luego por extensión a todo el dinero.

(Esta explicación ya fue propuesta antes por otros participantes, pero agrego una fuente impresa y prefiero usar la palabra "cambio" en lugar de otras como *morralla* o *dinero chatarra*, que me confundieron en lugar de aclarrame el concepto. A eso en Chile le decimos "el *sencillo*".)

Answer (score 0):

**Feria** en México tiene varias acepciones relativas al dinero con diferencias muy sutiles:

1. Sinónimo de dinero p.ej. *hizo mucha feria cuando se fue de bracero*
2. Cantidad de dinero en monedas o billetes de baja denominacion; sinónimo de morralla, suelto, etc. p.ej. *no traigo feria, traigo puros de a mil*
3. Equivalente en denominaciones menores de un billete o moneda p.ej. *¿Tienes feria de uno de quinientos?*
4. La cantidad de dinero remanente despues de hacer un pago; sinónimo de vuelto o cambio p. ej. *quédate con la feria*

Así, el verbo **feriar** (en México, conjugado como cambiar), aparte de significar convertir una ocacasión en festiva tembien tiene acepciones relativas al dinero:

1. Cambiar un billete o moneda por la misma cantidad en denominaciones menores p.ej. *¿Me puedes feriar un billete de cien?*
2. Quitar u obtener dinero por medio de robo o extorsión p. ej. *ayer detuvieron a dos tipos que andaban feriando en los colectivos*

La [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/feriar#conjugacionf9Tu0yV) aporta otros significados que no se utilizan en México.

En México también se usa **ferear** (conjugado como pelear) que, aunque es una hipercorrección, es muy común.